# import full .txt with SET !DATASOURCE not only certain line on imacros

Tags: imacros

I am trying to use the command

```
SET !DATASOURCE
```

to import the whole text from ".txt" file into some textbox
but I cannot find the exact command that would let me import/copy
the whole textfile into the box text, so far I have found `{{!COL1}}` in `SET !DATASOURCE` instruction page but It only imports the first line from the .txt file
and not full text

is there any way that I could import/copy whole text file?
and not only some certain lines!

code example:

```
SET !DATASOURCE TOPIC.txt
SET !DATASOURCE C:\TOPIC.txt
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00
URL GOTO=https://www.********.com
FRAME F=1
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY" CHARS="{{!COL1}}"
FRAME F=0
```

Using `Imacros software - Windows 64`

Answer (score 0):

Hum, "using iMacros (correct Spelling btw) Software" is a bit vague, if you don't mention the Version...! (And "Windows 64" also...)
=> FCI = `iMB v2021.0 'Trial' + Win10_x64`. (From your parallel Thread...)

---

But OK, same Answer/Solution like in your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:

- [Re: import full .txt with SET !DATASOURCE not only certain line](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31744&p=88048#p88048)

Yep..., '.TXT' Extension is perfect, (doesn't work with '.CSV' Extension), open your File in a TAB_2, (with `URL GOTO` + `file` Protocol), and extract it (=> `EXTRACT=TXT`) on `TYPE=PRE`, that will extract the whole Content of the File...
(`BODY` or `HTML` for the `TYPE` Param work also, but `PRE` is the "cleanest"...)

Drag your File from 'Windows Explorer' once to some open Tab in iMB (or any Browser), or open it through 'File > Open File' to get the full URL to reuse for `URL GOTO`...

That works with iMacros for FF v8.x (v8.8.2 + v8.9.7), I would think it (probably?) also works for iMB v2021.x, if it supports the `file` Protocol, which I would expect is the case... (I cannot try/test, I installed some 'Trial' Version a few months ago, is already long finished... )

... And just to be "clear", `URL GOTO` + `EXTRACT` do "the Job", you don't need `!DATASOURCE` + `!COLn`...